# Prevent a partition on a USB drive auto-mounting in Linux

Tags: linux, usb, partitioning, mount, usb-flash-drive

On Linux (Gnome desktop) how do you prevent one of the partitions on an external USB drive auto-mounting when it attached to the machine?

I don't just want to prevent the Nautilus window from popping up -- I want that partition not to mount.

Fiddling with /etc/fstab is not acceptable, as this is a removable drive that is attached to different machines.

I seem to remember that you create a hidden file in the root of the file system, but I can't remember what it's called. Something like:

```
touch /media/usbdisk/.no-mount
```

How do you actually make this work?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want the drive to not be auto-mounted on *any* linux machine, but without any configuration on the machine itself?

Answer (score 3):

To read that file, the partition would have to be mounted. The auto-mounting is a feature of the operating system (actually hotplug, or some other service monitoring USB) and has to be turned off per-machine.

Answer (score 2):

If you're specifically worried about auto-mounting in gnome, and would rather not touch */etc/fstab*, try the following command to turn it off for a specific partition:

```
gnome-mount --write-settings --mount-options noauto --device /dev/sda1
```

If you no longer want this to happen, erase the settings:

```
gnome-mount --erase-settings --device /dev/sda1
```

I also think you can turn off auto-mount altogether through the ***gconf-editor*** utililty: *desktop > gnome > volume_manager > automount_media*

I'm not aware of any way to have the auto-mount daemon look for a file on the drive and unmount the drive on finding it, though I can see the utility in having something like this.

Comment: I tried this, but it results in an error: 

Cannot mount volume - invalid mount option when attempting to mount the volume 'volume label'.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide the command you ran, and did you get the error when running the command or when attaching the device?

Comment: gnome-mount is not in recent distributions like Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid.  I've looked but haven't run across a way to do this now.  Any tips? The closest I've gotten is stopping all USB auto-opening [Disabling auto-open - Ask Ubuntu - Stack Exchange](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2444/disabling-auto-open)

Answer (score 0):

At first, run `udisksctl status` to get the device path, followed by eg. `udevadm info --attribute-walk --name=/dev/sr0`, to get the characteristics of the USB device to ignore.

Then add a rule with `UDISKS_IGNORE` into `/etc/udev/rules.d/12-prevent-automount.rules`. For example, this blocks the "HiSuite" "Linux File-CD Gadget" of a Huawei Matepad Pro 12.6", as the Windows software is rather irrelevant - and it's mount notifications are just as irrelevant:

```
ACTION=="add|change", SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sr[0-9]*", ATTRS{model}=="File-CD Gadget  ", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"
```

Then reload the rules with: `udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger`.

For testing the rule: `udevadm monitor --environment --udev`