# How can I prevent a specific USB drive from automounting?

Tags: linux, unix, mount, linux-mint

I have a USB drive that is, for all intensive purposes, permanently inserted. It's a licensing thumb drive for a Windows application I use.

How can I prevent Linux from automounting that drive, since I will never use it while on Linux. My specific flavor is Linux Mint 14 Cinnamon, but I'm assuming this might have something to do with fstab.

Comment: How does your automount works? If its based on udev, simply restrict this device by VID/PID.

Comment: I doubt it has anything to do with fstab (but if it does, just open up /etc/fstab and comment out the offending line).

Comment: auto-mounting using `fstab` takes place at the time of booting. Once loaded and running, fstab entries is not looked for unless told to using `mount -a` command.

Comment: Not to post duplicate content, here's my [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1667012/112466).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the usb is permanently plugged in you should be able to prevent the usb from auto-mounting with `/etc/fstab` file. An example of fstab entry follows.

`/dev/sdb1  /media/usb  auto    ro,noauto,user,exec 0 0`

If you don't want the device to be mounted automatically, use the `noauto` option as mentioned in the fourth column. With noauto, the device can be mounted only explicitly. Auto is the default option.

The first column specifies device name. Find your usb's device name using `sudo fdisk -l`.