# Replace Microsoft AD with samba4?

Tags: linux, samba, active-directory

I want to know if windows machines that exists in a domain can be replaced with linux machines and emulate the domain with its functionality, for example apply group policy or disable USB sticks on the linux machines

Answer (score 1):

You could replace your windows server with a samba4 server like [zentyal](http://www.zentyal.org).

First introduce it as a BDC, after this you should move the [FSMO](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/197132/) roles from the windows server to the zentyal (or the samba4 server) (using [dcpromo](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/254933/) in the windows server to downgrade the server as server and convert it to a normal client).

In that point you'll have to configure your GPO's for your windows machines to not allow the use of USB sticks, it's very easy using [RSAT](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Installing_RSAT_on_Windows_for_AD_Management) from a windows client machine.

If you want to use GNU/linux machines you have some options depending of the distro that you want to use.

Using an ubuntu/debian system you have to configure the [automount](https://superuser.com/questions/26570/prevent-a-partition-on-a-usb-drive-auto-mounting-in-linux) options to prevent the mounting of USB sticks.

If the number of GNU/linux machines are a lot to make changes one by one, you could replace GPO with software as [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/home) or [puppet](http://puppetlabs.com).